# Downgrade PHP 5.4 to 5.3 on bitnami ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php, php5, downgrade

I have to downgrade the php version of a bitnami ubuntu image to support some legacy codes. I tried to look for different methods that suggest using apt-get and dpkg to remove the 5.4 and install 5.3 of php version. However those steps don't work because the bitnami image doesn't have php installed through apt-get or dpkg.

Is there any other way that I should try to downgrade this server to have php v 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

Install the BitNami LAMP stack v5.3.22 instead of the v 5.4 stack

http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/cloud/amazon